# Insert through Linked Server from Azure VM to Managed Instance - fails when app runs it, succeeds when I run it in SSMS

Tags: sql-server, linked-server, oledbconnection, azure-sql-managed-instance

I am trying to insert into a table from an on-prem app, through a SQL Server 2019 instance running in a Azure VM (Windows), that has a linked server to an Azure Managed Instance. Due to <reasons I'm not going into>, we can't connect to Managed Instances from on-prem, but the (Entity Framework-based) app has to run on-prem. So I figured we could use a linked server on our VM in Azure, to bridge the gap.

I created a linked server on the SQL Server (VM), and then created views on the linked server and set up permissions across. When I run the below command it works, but when the app runs the same command, it fails with the below errors. I grabbed the query from a trace and ran it from the same server as the app, but in SSMS, using the same user as the app, connecting to the SQL VM, and it works. But when the App does it, I get the errors:

```
OLE DB provider "MSOLEDBSQL" for linked server "My_LS" returned message "The parameter is incorrect.".
```

followed by

```
The OLE DB provider "MSOLEDBSQL" for linked server "My_LS" reported an error. One or more arguments were reported invalid by the provider.
```

if I look for errors on the VM, I also get:

```
The operation could not be performed because OLE DB provider "MSOLEDBSQL" for linked server "MEDRX01_LS" was unable to begin a distributed transaction.
```

The insert statement is:

```
exec sp_executesql N'INSERT [dbo].[mytable]([fieldb], [fieldc], [fieldd], [fielde], [fieldf], [fieldg], [fieldh], [fieldi], [fieldj])
VALUES (@0, @1, @2, @3, @4, @5, @6, @7, @8)
SELECT [id]
FROM [dbo].[mytable]
WHERE @@ROWCOUNT > 0 AND [id] = scope_identity()',N'@0 int,@1 datetime2(7),@2 datetime2(7),@3 datetime2(7),@4 varchar(10),@5 varchar(20),@6 varchar(5),@7 varchar(20),@8 bit',@0=35,@1='2023-04-19 10:43:25.8661564',@2='2023-04-19 10:43:25.6911413',@3='2023-04-23 10:43:25.6911413',@4='12345678',@5='AB12344R',@6='R4321',@7='123456789A',@8=0
```

and here is the linked server - I have tried with "enable promotion" set to both true and false. Again, it works when I run it, but not when the app does. Oddly, it says SQLNCLI below, but when I look in the GUI it says "Microsoft OLE DB Provider for SQL Server". I created another linked server explicitly using MSOLEDBSQL for the provider, same issue.

```
/****** Object:  LinkedServer [My_LS]    Script Date: 4/19/2023 10:56:45 AM ******/
EXEC master.dbo.sp_addlinkedserver @server = N'My_LS', @srvproduct=N'', @provider=N'SQLNCLI', @datasrc=N'myazuremi.DATABASE.WINDOWS.NET'
 /* For security reasons the linked server remote logins password is changed with ######## */
EXEC master.dbo.sp_addlinkedsrvlogin @rmtsrvname=N'My_LS',@useself=N'False',@locallogin=NULL,@rmtuser=N'nopermissions',@rmtpassword='########'
EXEC master.dbo.sp_addlinkedsrvlogin @rmtsrvname=N'My_LS',@useself=N'False',@locallogin=N'userA',@rmtuser=N'userA',@rmtpassword='########'
EXEC master.dbo.sp_addlinkedsrvlogin @rmtsrvname=N'My_LS',@useself=N'False',@locallogin=N'userB',@rmtuser=N'userB',@rmtpassword='########'
EXEC master.dbo.sp_addlinkedsrvlogin @rmtsrvname=N'My_LS',@useself=N'False',@locallogin=N'userC',@rmtuser=N'userC',@rmtpassword='########'
EXEC master.dbo.sp_addlinkedsrvlogin @rmtsrvname=N'My_LS',@useself=N'False',@locallogin=N'myuser',@rmtuser=N'myuser',@rmtpassword='########'
GO
EXEC master.dbo.sp_serveroption @server=N'My_LS', @optname=N'collation compatible', @optvalue=N'false'
GO
EXEC master.dbo.sp_serveroption @server=N'My_LS', @optname=N'data access', @optvalue=N'true'
GO
EXEC master.dbo.sp_serveroption @server=N'My_LS', @optname=N'dist', @optvalue=N'false'
GO
EXEC master.dbo.sp_serveroption @server=N'My_LS', @optname=N'pub', @optvalue=N'false'
GO
EXEC master.dbo.sp_serveroption @server=N'My_LS', @optname=N'rpc', @optvalue=N'true'
GO
EXEC master.dbo.sp_serveroption @server=N'My_LS', @optname=N'rpc out', @optvalue=N'false'
GO
EXEC master.dbo.sp_serveroption @server=N'My_LS', @optname=N'sub', @optvalue=N'false'
GO
EXEC master.dbo.sp_serveroption @server=N'My_LS', @optname=N'connect timeout', @optvalue=N'0'
GO
EXEC master.dbo.sp_serveroption @server=N'My_LS', @optname=N'collation name', @optvalue=null
GO
EXEC master.dbo.sp_serveroption @server=N'My_LS', @optname=N'lazy schema validation', @optvalue=N'false'
GO
EXEC master.dbo.sp_serveroption @server=N'My_LS', @optname=N'query timeout', @optvalue=N'0'
GO
EXEC master.dbo.sp_serveroption @server=N'My_LS', @optname=N'use remote collation', @optvalue=N'true'
GO
EXEC master.dbo.sp_serveroption @server=N'My_LS', @optname=N'remote proc transaction promotion', @optvalue=N'true'
GO
```

Any help appreciated.

Comment: does it work from ssms if you wrap the call in begin tran exec sp....  commit tran?

Comment: @siggemannen it does NOT! Nice catch. I found a comment in a microsoft thread by Conor Cunningham: "If you are running from EF or similar, please check to make sure that it is not starting a DTC on your behalf." And I found, in the code:  `result = executionStrategy.Execute(() => SaveChangesToStore(options, executionStrategy, startLocalTransaction: true));`  But still no idea how to fix it. App dev is looking.

Comment: Yeah, cross server transactions is something I try to avoid at all cost since it's "impossible" to get working reliably. You should be able to disable it, unfortunately I'm not expert in ORM mappers like EF

Comment: @siggemannen ditto.  However, it appears that EF can't turn off distributed transactions, so we're going to see if we can change it to a stored procedure and have the app use that instead. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0):

Check if collation is same, Drivers are compatible, make sure to have latest OLEDB provider, Ensure the option **Allow inprocess** is ticked for the ***Microsoft OLE DB Driver for SQL Server*** in its properties in the **Linked Server | Providers**.

Below limitations currently apply to distributed transactions (also known as elastic transactions or natively supported distributed transactions) in Azure SQL Managed Instance:

a). With this technology, only transactions across databases in managed instances are supported. For all other scenarios that may include X/Open XA resource providers and databases outside of Azure SQL Managed Instance you should configure DTC for Azure SQL Managed Instance.

b). Transactions across WCF services aren't supported. For example, you have a WCF service method that executes a transaction. Enclosing the call within a transaction scope will fail as a System.ServiceModel.ProtocolException.

c). Azure SQL Managed Instance must be part of a Server trust group in order to participate in distributed transaction.
Limitations of Server trust groups affect distributed transactions.

d). Managed Instances that participate in distributed transactions need to have connectivity over private endpoints (using private IP address from the virtual network where they are deployed) and need to be mutually referenced using private FQDNs. Client applications can use distributed transactions on private endpoints. Additionally, in cases when Transact-SQL leverages linked servers referencing private endpoints, client applications can use distributed transactions on public endpoints as well.

Reference: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-sql/database/elastic-transactions-overview?view=azuresql